# roots of system of nonlinear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I can't get any solutions beside when $x=0\vee y=0 \vee z=0$
$$yz-2x\lambda-2x\mu=0\tag{1}$$
$$xz-2y\mu=0\tag{2}$$
$$xy-4z\lambda =0\tag{3}$$
$$x^2+y^2=4\tag{4}$$
$$x^2+2z^2=3\tag{5}$$
Can you help me? I seem to be doing algebraic manipulation that lead me nowhere.

Comment: Using Mathematica http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[{x^2+%2B+2*z^2+%3D%3D+3%2C+x^2+%2B+y^2+%3D%3D+4%2C+x*y+-+4*z*l+%3D%3D+0%2C++++x*z+-+2*y*p+%3D%3D+0%2C+y*z+-+2*x*l+-+2*x*p+%3D%3D+0}%2C+{x%2C+y%2C+z%2C+l%2C+p}], I get 16 different solutions for x,y,z,$\lambda$,$mu$.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but this system is what I have to solve for constrained optimization in exam, where I have to solve this kind of things without using electronic devices...

Comment: Just saw that the Link isn't represented correctly. Copy the whole data until (without) the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From (4) and (5) we obtain:

$$y^2z^2=(4-x^2)(3-x^2)/2......(6)$$

From (1) we obtain:
$$y^2z^2=4x^2(\lambda+\mu)^2......(7)$$

From (6)-(7) we have:
$$(4-x^2)(3-x^2)=8x^2(\lambda+\mu)^2...(8)$$

We can then solve $x^2$ from (8).

Once $x$ is solved, we can then solve other equations (4) and (5) for $y$ and $z$...

Comment: I feel dumb, but how do I get x from (8)?

Comment: (8) is a quadratic equation in $x^2$.

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand. If I had for example $(4-x^2)(3-x^2)=0$ I would know. But here to get 0 on one side I have to substract and I am left with $(4-x^2)(3-x^2)-8x^2(\lambda+\mu)^2=0$

Comment: So $x^2= (1/2)*(7 + 8*A^2 + \sqrt{1 + 112*A^2 + 64*A^4})$ where $A=(\lambda+\mu)^2$.